# How to access path url parameter in DRF serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

**Short question:**

What's the appropriate way to access a **url path parameter** (not a url *query* parameter) in a Django DRF serializer?
For example, how to get the `blogid` value in `/api/blogposts/:blogid/comments`.

**Context:**

A have a Django DRF api, where I have a url similar to :

```
/api/blogposts/:blogid/comments
```

that is handled by a generic view:

```
from rest_framework import generics

class MyCommentsView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
       queryset = Comment.objects.all()
       serializer_class = CommentSerializer
```

(`blog` and `comment` are just example resources; i am working with different ones)

This view allows via a POST call to create new comments.
For legacy reasons, the request will contain the `blog_id` also as a request body parameter.

In my Serializer I want to check if the `:blogid` in the url is identical to the `blog_id` in the body. Currently I do the following, but the path splitting and element selecting feels very fragile (e.g. if I restructure my url in `urls.py` I need to adjust my custom  parsing) . So, is there a better way?

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = [..., 'blog_id', ... ]

    ...

    def validate_blog_id(self, value):
        # Better way for next line?
        blogid_in_url = int(self.context['request'].path.split('/')[-2]) 
        if blogid_in_url != value:
             ...
```

**Note:**
my question is about a **url path parameter**, not a url query parameter (like `blogid` in `api/blogposts?blogid=55`). I know a url query parameter can be accessed via `self.context['request'].query_params`.

Comment: I'd suggest you to take a look on the [`drf-nested-routers`](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) library, it will allow you to use `Routers` and nest resources like that, providing you with the `blog_id`/`blog_pk` directly in some view methods, as well as making it available through your `self.kwargs` inside the view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can't say it is a good way but suggest alternatively:

You can access your url parameters in your serializer like this:

```
self.context.get('request').parser_context.get('kwargs').get(
        'blog_id') # your url parameter name here
```

Another way, you can override create method of `ListCreateAPIView`;

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    blog_id = kwargs.get('blog_id') # your url parameter name here
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, 
                                     context={'blog_id': blog_id})
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                    headers=headers)
```

Comment: Looks like both are good solutions, and better then mine. The second one is more explicit, but as I don't have a need for a custom `create` (appart from this use case) I'll go for your first approach.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using generics API views like `ListCreateAPIView`, you can access the url parameters in your serializer like:

```py
blog_id = self.context['view'].kwargs["blog_id"]
```